# display:none not working for table inside div

Tags: html, css

I have this text which when clicked on should show the table.

```
<div id="lastten" ng-controller="LastTenbuilds">
    <div ng-click="lasttenBuilds();" onclick="showlasttenbuilds();">Get List of Last Ten </div>
    <table class="featuretable" id="lasttenBuildsTable">            
    <thead >
        <!--change style of column with css-->

        <tr >
            <th class="Header">Total</th>
            <th class="Header">Passed</th>
            <th class="Header">Failed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody><!--display none-->
    <!--onclick-->                                              
        <tr ng-repeat="case in lastten">                        
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Total}}</td>
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Passed}}</td>
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Failed}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My CSS has

```css
#lasttenBuildsTable{
    display:none !important;
}

table.featuretable {
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-collapse:
collapse; border-spacing: 0;

}

table.featuretable td, th {

border: 1px solid transparent;
height: 30px;
transition: all 0.3s; 
overflow: hidden;
}

table.featuretable th {

font-weight: bold;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: :middle;
}

table.featuretable td {

text-align: center;
vertical-align: :middle;
}
```

so the table should be hidden before the text is clicked. But it's not hidden. In chrome's inspect element, the `display:none` is crossed. Someone knows the problem?

Okay, the !important does hide it but the the onlick/ng-click is not showing it back. I added onlick in the tag for now just to check if it worked.

Here's the js-

```
function showlasttenbuilds(){
                document.getElementById("lasttenBuildsTable").style.display="Block";
            }
```

Comment: Yeah, you have a rule that overrides that display, for sure an `!important` in that rule. Share at least your CSS please.

Comment: It's occurring due to higher specificity of `display:` coming from somewhere else inside the code. Can you share a working Fiddle

Comment: Can u provide .featuretable CSS?

Comment: Okay, Added the css.

Comment: for angular  you can use ng-show ,ng-hide instead of css property

Comment: !important should work

Comment: okay, the important is hiding it but then the function to show it is not working. I still can't find anything that's overriding the css for the id.

Comment: Your provided code does what you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/bnja17d0/ . There is something else going on.

Comment: !important would be overiding the "show" style.

Comment: hmm ? So if i make it !important i can't change it throught js ?

Comment: You can, but it is harder, which is why `!important` should be avoided unless absolutely required.Use the **Computed** tab in Developer Tools to see the "cascade" of styles applied to the element. Expand "Display" to see what is setting the display property (and what is being over-ridden)

Comment: element.style {
    display: block; No idea why this is block !!!
}
#lasttenBuildsTable {
    display: none;  This is crossed.
}

Comment: Something, possibly angular, is applying that inline style

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#lasttenBuildsTable{ display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look may be this would help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHide").click(function(){
        $(".featuretable").toggleClass("display-table");
    });
});
```

```css
.featuretable{
    display:none !important ;
}

.display-table{
  display:block !important;
  }

table.featuretable {
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-collapse:
collapse; border-spacing: 0;

}

table.featuretable td, th {

border: 1px solid transparent;
height: 30px;
transition: all 0.3s; 
overflow: hidden;
}

table.featuretable th {

font-weight: bold;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: :middle;
}

table.featuretable td {

text-align: center;
vertical-align: :middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lastten" ng-controller="LastTenbuilds">
  <input type="button" value="toggleTable" id="showHide" />
    <div ng-click="lasttenBuilds();">Get List of Last Ten </div>
    <table class="featuretable" id="lasttenBuildsTable">            
    <thead >
        <!--change style of column with css-->

        <tr >
            <th class="Header">Total</th>
            <th class="Header">Passed</th>
            <th class="Header">Failed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody><!--display none-->
    <!--onclick-->                                              
        <tr ng-repeat="case in lastten">                        
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Total}}</td>
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Passed}}</td>
            <td colspan="1" >{{case.Failed}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `!important` is an absulute last resort: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Comment: The main thing is why isn't the css working! . Obv, we could fix it that way.